# Iphone jump through input manually

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, input

Im making a script with javascript/jquery that jumps to the next input when user press enter. In every browser works fine except safari/chrome for **iphone**. 
Looks like the keyboard of iphone bugs the script or something similar. My html basically is this:

```
<form onsubmit='return false'>
    <input type='text' id='firstInput'>
    <input type='text' id='secondInput'>
</form>
```

And my JS basically is this:

```
$('#firstInput').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){ 
        $("input").blur(); //just to close keyboard
        $("#secondInput").focus();// doesnt focus the input neither opens the keyboard
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding a setTimeout to the focus will solve this issue on safari for iphone, chrome for ios looks like dont have any solution to do this.